# El modulo me sale de forma incorrecta en la class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

He puesto en una class un modulo, pero el modulo me sale primero y la class me sale segundo, yo quiero que primero me salga dato_mania.busquedad() y después me salga dato_mania.buscado(). El modulo lo realice por función, porque con class no me salia para print, quiero saber como podría hacer para que me salga primero la class y después la función de forma ordenada. Acá dejo el código:

class

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import buscadoranime

class Buscador:
  def __init__(self, buscador):
    self.buscador = buscador

  def busquedad(self):
    variable = ("¿La busquedad sera por anime o manga?")
    print(variable)
    self.buscador = input()

class Data(Buscador):
  def __init__(self):
    super()

  def buscado(self):
    animesfor = buscadoranime.anime
    if self.buscador == "anime":
     print(animesfor)
    elif self.buscador == "manga":
     print("¿Que manga buscas?")
    else:
     print("Eso no se encuentra")

dato_mania = Data()

dato_mania.busquedad()

dato_mania.buscado()

input()
```

modulo

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def anime():
  variable1 = ("¿Que anime buscas?")
  print(variable1)
  buscadoranime = input()
  if buscadoranime == "naruto":
   print("El anime es shonen")
  elif buscadoranime == "doraemon":
   print("El anime es comedia")
  else:
   print("No esta en la busquedad")
  return variable1
anime()

input()
```

[image: La función me sale primero y la class me sale segundo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, te cuento...

Empezamos por el módulo.

No sé por qué motivo, al final del todo tienes puesto `input()`. Por otro lado, ¿por qué guardas la pregunta en una variable para luego hacerle `print()` y después un `input()` suelto sí pues usar `input()` y meterle dentro la pregunta y que el usuario pueda responder guardándolo en una variable? Tu problema con el orden de ejecución reside en que por algún motivo el cual desconozco, estás llamando a la función `anime()` dentro del mismo archivo y al hacerle `import` en el otro se le llama a la función mostrando la pregunta del módulo. Para finalizar con esto, yo cambiaria los `print()` por `returns`, porque en la clase lo estás guardando en una variable para enseñarlo en el `print()` del `if`, pero al ser print el módulo y no retornar nada, la variable `animesfor` es `undefined`.

El módulo corregido quedaría así:

```py
def anime():
  buscadoranime = input("¿Que anime buscas? \n")
  if buscadoranime == "naruto":
   return "El anime es shonen"
  elif buscadoranime == "doraemon":
   return "El anime es comedia"
  else:
   return "No esta en la busquedad"
```

Por otro lado, el archivo de la clase.

En la función `busqueda()` pasa lo mismo que lo del `input()` y el `print()` del módulo. Sobra, al igual que en el archivo del módulo, el `input()` del final del archivo. Por último, mete la llamada a `buscadoranime.anime()` dentro del if, porque si pones que buscas manga, te pregunta que anime buscas igualmente.

Estás haciendo un constructor que no tiene nada, te podrías ahorrar en ambos el `__init__`, yo en mi caso no los he quitado, pero podrías quitar ambos y el código funcionaria exactamente igual, ahorrándote líneas de código.

El archivo editado quedaría así:

```py
import buscadoranime

class Buscador:
  def __init__(self, buscador):
    self.buscador = buscador

  def busquedad(self):
    self.buscador = input("¿La busquedad sera por anime o manga? \n")

class Data(Buscador):
  def __init__(self):
    super()

  def buscado(self):
    if self.buscador == "anime":
     animesfor = buscadoranime.anime()
     print(animesfor)
    elif self.buscador == "manga":
     print("¿Que manga buscas?")
    else:
     print("Eso no se encuentra")

dato_mania = Data()

dato_mania.busquedad()

dato_mania.buscado()
```

Comment: pongo input(), porque en el block de nota donde coloco el codigo, me permite leerlo dando doble clic y verlo en pantalla.

Comment: Y lo pongo en un modulo porque usando self.anime, self.manga y self.buscador no podía usar input() para los 3 self.

Comment: cuando pongo tu código me sale un espacio negro al comienzo y no empieza con que la busqueda sera por anime o manga ?

Comment: @nekordemon Si te refieres a que tiends que darle a intro y luego sale la pregunta, entiendo que has dejado el input() del final, es por eso

Comment: Ya no sale el espacio en blanco a la primera, pero cuando respondo la pregunta ¿Qué anime buscas? y pongo naruto, se cierra la pantalla.

Comment: ya me funciono, puse el input() dentro del codigo de if y else.

Comment: @nekordemon pues ya estaria entnces